# Grouped rows are duplicated if using COUNT DISCTINCT + ORDER BY DESC

Tags: mysql, sql

A strange thing started to happen after updating my MySQL server from version 5 to version 8.

I have a table called `Events`:

```
ClientId Varchar(32)
Time TIMESTAMP
...
Some more irrelevant columns
```

There are no unusual things, just plain table, no foreign keys, index on `ClientId` and `Time`.

If I make a query like this:

```
SELECT
    DATE(`Time`) AS D,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ClientId) AS C1
FROM
    Events
WHERE
    TIME >= '2020-10-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY
    D
ORDER BY
    D;
```

The result is as expected - 34 rows containing the data.

However if I add just the `DESC` to the `ORDER BY`, the result is strange:

```
SELECT DATE(Time) AS D
     , COUNT(DISTINCT ClientId) AS C1 
  FROM Events 
 WHERE Time >= '2020-10-01 00:00:00' 
 GROUP 
    BY D 
 ORDER 
    BY D DESC;

+------------+------+
| D          | C1   |
+------------+------+
| 2020-11-03 | 2104 |
| 2020-11-02 | 2017 |
| 2020-11-03 |   46 | -- duplicated 2020-11-03?
| 2020-11-01 |  431 |
| 2020-11-02 |   39 |
| 2020-11-01 | 1665 | -- duplicated 2020-11-01?
| 2020-10-31 | 1320 |
| 2020-11-01 |   67 |
...
total of 86 rows
```

Lots of rows are duplicated.

I tried rebuilding the table, but with no changes.
Tried the same query on different tables, the result is similar if `DATE(xyz`) + `COUNT DISTINCT` + `GROUP BY DESC` are used at once.

Is there something wrong with my query or is it an engine bug?
Current version `8.0.21`

Comment: Changing the `order by` clause of a query does not affect the number of rows it returns.

Comment: Thats the point. It shouldnt, but it does.

Comment: Then are you able to build a minimum reproducible that demonstrates the issue, as DDL and DML statements? You can use https://dbfiddle.uk/ if that helps; their MySQL version is 8.0.22 as of now.

Comment: for now I copied the table to different server and results there are fine. using the same mysql version 8.0.21. strange.

Comment: i also tried duplicating the table on the same server - bad results...

Comment: found related mysql bug in tracker: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101228

Answer (score 1):

Looks like MySQL bug:
`date group and sort groups similar dates in different groups`
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101228